# AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<String?> crash - bug in compiler?

Tags: swift, cocoa, swift2, xcode7, xcode7-beta6

I'm slowly migrating my codebase to Swift and came across a weird crash, where I'm populating an `AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<String?>` with a non-nil string. Here is some scaled down code:

```
extension String {
    func getRegexVariableNamed(name: String, forRegexString regexString: String) -> String? {
        /** ... **/
        return "TO BE IMPLEMENTED".lowercaseString // Using lowercase to prevent the compiler from inlining
    }
}

class XYZ {
    func extractInformation(info1: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<String?>, info2: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<String?>, info3: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<String?>, info4: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<String?>, fromSource source: String) -> Bool {
        guard let vp = source.getRegexVariableNamed("ID", forRegexString: "vp=(?P<ID>\\d+)") else {
            return false
        }

        info4.memory = vp
        info1.memory = "ABC"
        info2.memory = "DEF"
        info3.memory = "GHI" + vp
        return true
    }
}

// Code in playground
let obj = XYZ()

let info1 = AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<String?>()
let info2 = AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<String?>()
let info3 = AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<String?>()
let info4 = AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<String?>()
if !obj.extractInformation(info1, info2: info2, info3: info3, info4: info4, fromSource: "") {
    print("NO")
}else{
    print("YES")
}
```

The app (and the same applies for the playground) crashes with `error: Playground execution aborted: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).`

This exception happens on setting a string to the `AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer` in the method `extractInformation(...)`.

I wanted to check if I'm not doing something wrong here before I report this as a bug to Apple.

BTW I'm using the latest Xcode 7 beta (6) on OS X 10.10.5.

P.S.: I know the more Swift-ly approach would be to make a method that returns a struct instead of using these autoreleasing pointers, but as mentioned, I am slowly moving from ObjC, so I need it (for now) to be backward-compatible.

Comment: Since no one seems to be able to point to an issue in the code, rather than the compiler, I've submitted this bug to Apple.

Answer (score 1):

With Xcode 7.0.1, I can make your code work, with some changes.

First of all, in the [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C (Swift 2)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html) guide ("Autoreleasing Pointers" chapter), it says that a function declared as taking an `AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<Type>` can accept an `inout` expression of the same `Type`.

So, the code could be changed as following:

```
let info1: String?
let info2: String?
let info3: String?
let info4: String?
if !obj.extractInformation(&info1, info2: &info2, info3: &info3, info4: &info4, fromSource: "") {
    print("NO")
}else{
    print("YES")
}
```

But, it's still not working.

However, in the same page, it says that `AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<Type>` is applied for **class** types mapping. 
I don't know if this is the reason it's not working, difficult to guess what's happening behind, but if you replace `String` with `NSString`, you'll get a result.

```
extension String {
    func getRegexVariableNamed(name: String, forRegexString regexString: String) -> String? {
        /** ... **/
        return "TO BE IMPLEMENTED".lowercaseString // Using lowercase to prevent the compiler from inlining
    }
}

class XYZ {
    func extractInformation(info1: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>,
                            info2: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>,
                            info3: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>,
                            info4: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>,
                            fromSource source: String) -> Bool {
        guard let vp = source.getRegexVariableNamed("ID", forRegexString: "vp=(?P<ID>\\d+)") else {
            return false
        }

        info4.memory = vp
        info1.memory = "ABC"
        info2.memory = "DEF"
        info3.memory = "GHI" + vp
        return true
    }
}

// Code in playground
let obj = XYZ()

var info1: NSString?
var info2: NSString?
var info3: NSString?
var info4: NSString?
if !obj.extractInformation(&info1, info2: &info2, info3: &info3, info4: &info4, fromSource: "") {
    print("NO")
}else{
    print("YES")
    info1                // "ABC"
    info2                // "DEF"
    info3                // "GHIto be implemented"
    info4                // "to be implemented"
}
```

Comment: Interesting, that it works with NSString - since even the pure Swift code with String doesn't work. I eventually rewrote all the classes that used this kind of stuff into Swift and embedded all the variables into a struct, so it's not an issue anymore. But it's definitely one of the issues that make me think that Swift simply isn't production-ready yet - as most Apple technologies, they start being usable 2 years after introduction...